# Attach mail message to mail in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, email-attachments

In a Rails 5.1 ActionMailer, I want to attach a Mail object to an e-mail:

```
def attach_mail(original_email)
  attachments['original-email.eml'] = { mime_type: 'message/rfc822', encoding: '7bit', content: original_email.to_s }
  mail to: 'postmaster', subject: 'mail should be attached'
end
```

However, this does not produce valid e-mails. Thunderbird lists the attachment with size '0'. Horde lists the attachment with correct size, but does not recognize it as an e-mail.

I've tried variations of the `attachments` line:

```
attachments['original-email.eml'] = original_email
attachments['original-email.eml'] = { content: original_email.to_s }
attachments['original-email.eml'] = { mime_type: 'message/rfc822', content: original_email.to_s }
```

but none of these result in an e-mail with an e-mail attachment.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out.

To attach an email (Mail object from the 'mail' gem) to an ActionMailer message, you need to specify the MIME type and encoding like so:

```
def attach_mail(original_email)
  attachments['original-email.eml'] = { mime_type: 'message/rfc822', 
    encoding: '7bit',
    content: original_email.to_s }
  mail to: 'postmaster', subject: 'mail should be attached'
end
```

This creates a `multipart/mixed` message which is properly displayed in MUAs.

However, if you happen to add any inline attachment (e.g. to display a logo image in the ActionMailer e-mail body), the entire message will have a `multipart/related` mime type. The MUAs that I tried were unable to interpret a `multipart/related` message with an e-mail attachment.

Therefore, refrain from adding any inline attachments when attaching an e-mail to an e-mail.

Comment: Thank you that you documented this here!
I was stumped why just the mail messages were garbled.

Comment: I further had an issue that occured with mails having only a html body with an attached eml file. There the attachment garbled the whole mail at delivery. While strangely converting the Mail object via it's encoded method to an .eml file itself it was working. In the end i'm now sending eml-attachments with mime_type: 'application/octet-stream', encoding: '7bit' which seems to work best for my various formats. At least until i stumble over the next weird combination that will fail in one or another MUA

Comment: @neongrau, perfect, with `application/octet-stream` I'm able to successfully attach .eml messages to an e-mail. Even in combination with inline attachments!